# Print output of some my data in a file that should start with first line without blank space

Tags: text-processing, files

By using some shell command i filter some output
Please can some one suggest how i can print this output in some file

For example 
I filtered some line and save it to some file but problem is it is starting with 2 nd line 
in first line it is showing blank line in second line it is showing my output can any one suggest how i can print my data in first line of file means how we can delet that space

```
cat file1 | awk '{if ($2==$3) { print }}' | awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8}' > file
```

Comment: Can you post an example input, an example actual output and an example expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '{if ($2==$3) { print }}' file1 | \
    awk '{print $5, $6, $7, $8}' | tail -n +2 > file
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Could you please take a few moments to explain your answer a bit? We generally like our A's to be more than just a line of code. Thanks!